# Multiple Bitbucket accounts on same machine

Tags: bitbucket

I need to implement multiple bitbucket accounts on same machine.

I set user name and email locally but did not work

git: 'credential-[here show global user]' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://username@bitbucket.org/xyz/xyz.git/'

Comment: set user `git config --global user.name "UserName"`

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Window 10 64 bit,

Comment: @SuneelKumar 
i need to set multiple bitbucket account having diff username so how i set them globaly?

Comment: The username and email used in Git are only related to commits; they are not used to authenticate to any remote repo.

OP, which client are you using?

Comment: i am using git commands in cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this issue by setting my remote url with my password
here you can check

```
git remote -v
origin  https://USERNAME@github.com/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://USERNAME@github.com/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

now set your remote url like this

```
git remote set-url origin USERNAME:password@github.com/REPOSITORY.git
```

that it now on every command git never ask you about password